# Check Microsoft SQL Server Edition without executing @@version query manually on each system

Tags: sql-server, windows, scripting, registry

I need to check "*Microsoft SQL Server*" **Edition**  e.g. **Standard, Express or Enterprise** etc (**not the version details**) installed on multiple system, but to get the edition details I've to manually execute `@@version` query on each *SQL Server Management Studio* window or console, which returns edition as well as version details. Is there is any other method or script which correctly checks the edition of  MS SQL Server installed on the system from backend without manually executing the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS Edition
```

If you don't want to execute the query at all, you can also parse the sql log (error log). Very first lines for each log contain the edition

EDIT:  The log can be viewed either programmatically using xp_readerrorlog SP, or the path can be found at \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLxx.instance\MSSQLServer\Parameters --> look at -e switch

Or via registry.

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLxx.*instance*\Setup  --> Edition